# Java polymorphism and runtime method matching

Tags: java, polymorphism, runtime

For example I have following code.

```
class Circle {
    double radius;

    public boolean equals(Object circle) {
        return this.radius ==((Circle)circle).radius;
    }
}
```

And a Driver

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object circle1 = new Circle();
        Circle circle2 = new Circle();
        System.out.println(circle1.equals(circle2));

    }
}
```

It prints True, but if I re-write Circle.equals() as

```
public boolean equals(Circle circle) {
    return this.radius ==((Circle)circle).radius;
}
```

where .equals() method takes Circle type, system would output False.
I know that Circle class is subclass of Object class, So compiler does not report error and at Runtime, JVM chooses correct override method to implement correct behavior. 
If I modify code as bottom one, where .equals() takes Circle Class objects, Code can implement correctly, please tell me why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the method signature

```
public boolean equals(Circle circle) {
```

You are *overloading* `equals`, not overriding it; this is not a compiler error.  That means that `Circle` will inherit the `Object` implementation of `equals`, which simply compares object references to see if they are equal.  This returns `false`.

Your `equals` method should take an `Object` to override the method properly.  You should also use the `@Override` annotation, which will produce a compiler error if the annotated method doesn't override a method in the superclass.  The meethod body should test if its argument is an instance of the class before casting, so it can return `false` instead of throwing a `ClassCastException`.

Additionally, it's always a good idea to override `hashCode` if you are overriding `equals`.

Comment: If I write code like bottom one, where `Circle.equals(Object circle)` this will Override .equals() in Object because it will implement different signature. However, if `Circle.equals(Circle circle)` then it is overload??

Comment: Yes, an overloaded method is 2 or more methods with the same name yet different parameter(s) (number, types).  Here, one is inherited `equals(Object)` and the other you declared `equals(Circle)`.

Comment: If I overload method in Subclass, but I created a Superclass instance. If superclass instance invokes overloaded method that is subclass. Would it implement correctly, I mean to invoke method in super class or subclass

Comment: Please see a [polymorphism tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: As you said, if I overloaded .equals() method in Circle class. As dynamic binding, instance Object circle 1 = new Circle(), searching equals() in Circle first? Or it does not work this way.

Answer (score 2):

In Java return types are covariant, that means you can use subclass as return type for the overrided method.
For example, this is valid :

```
public class Foo{
    @Override
    public Foo clone(){
        ...
    }
}
```

But parameter types are not covariant.  So you overload the method  in the second code,  you don't override it.

Annotate the method with `@Override` and it will not compile any longer:

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Circle circle) {
    return this.radius ==((Circle)circle).radius;
}
```